# Implementar o this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existem diversas divs com a classe `.categorias` e eu preciso exibir o elemento `.nav-a` somente na div categoria que eu estiver com o mouse em cima dela no momento.

O que está acontecendo atualmente é que quando eu passo o mouse sobre qualquer uma das divs `.categorias` ele exibe o `.nav-a` em todas elas, e não só na `.categorias` em questão.

Segue o código atual para referência.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-a').hide();

    $('.categorias').mouseenter(function(){
         $('.nav-a').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.categorias').mouseleave(function(){
         $('.nav-a').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Se o .nav-a for filho do .categorias, faça isso $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeIn(); ou $(this + '.nav-a').fadeIn() e diga-me se deu certo, seria interessante postar seu HTML

Comment: Posta também o HTML, para entendermos como está o seu DOM.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Independentemente do HTML, sua primeira sugestão parece correta. Poste isso como resposta!

Comment: A propósito, estou assumindo que a animação de mostrar e esconder é importante pra você, certo? Caso contrário, uma solução simplesmente com CSS seria suficiente (e se o alvo forem browsers modernos, mesmo o caso da animação - [usando CSS3 `transition`s](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/))

Comment: Obrigado, a solução do Diego Vieira resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Só uma dica: se vai ficar usando direto o mesmo seletor, e se a quantidade de itens obtidos não vai mudar, transforma o `$(".nav-a")` numa variável. Tipo `var foo = $(".nav-a");`. Isso vai facilitar sua vida mais pra frente ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize dessa forma

***Jquery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-a').hide();

    $('.categorias').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.categorias').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Outra forma de fazer e "minimizar código"

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.categorias')
     .mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeIn();
    })
     .mouseleave(function(){
          $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Muito bem observado pelo nosso amigo [@RonnyAmarante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4447/ronny-amarante) remova isso do seu código:
 `$('.nav-a').hide();` e faça o no seu CSS.

***CSS***

```
.nav-a {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Apenas para complementar a resposta correta do @DiegoVieira, você também pode agrupar esses eventos da seguinte forma:

**Dica**: `$('.nav-a').hide()`, utilize seu CSS para isso.

```
$( '.categorias' ).on({
     mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeIn();
  }, mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.nav-a').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: Eu iria colocar mais opções agora, acha necessário eu reeditar minha resposta?